# Refining data set using R studio

Tags: r, excel, functional-programming, logic

[SampleData.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1sCHpF9HwxJX2VUTnJEWjhWN1NBQW4zaGl6dGd2cnBKSVJB/view?usp=sharing)

Type    A1001   A1002   A1003   A1004   A1005   Total
TypeA
TypeB
TypeC
TypeD
Total

I have to refine the data set in the above form using R programming. Looking for an IDEA to count each type of communication w.r.t UserID

```
     *

data11 <- read.xlsx("SampleData.xlsx", sheetName = "SampleData1", header = TRUE)
data22 <- read.xlsx("SampleData.xlsx", sheetName = "SampleData2", header = TRUE)
dim(data11)
dim(data22)
data2 = data22[complete.cases(data22),]
data2$User <- as.character(data2$User)
data1$User = NA
for(i in data1[,1])
{
  for(q in data2[,1])
  {
      if(data1$Id[i] == data2$Id[q])
      {
  data1$User[i] = data2$User[q]
      }
  }
}
data.1 = data1[complete.cases(data1),]
 x1 <- subset(data.1, Type == "Email" )
 x2 <- subset(data.1, Type == "Update" )
x3 <- subset(data.1, Type == "NA" )
x4 <- subset(data.1, Type == "Call" )
x5 <- subset(data.1, Type == "Visit" )
p1 = as.list(as.data.frame(count(x1, "User")))
Type1 = p1$freq
```

*

**As you can see from the last two lines of CODE. I tried something but it is the wrong way.**

Help me out

Comment: You need to decide whetehr your objects are named `data11`, `data22` or `data1`,`data2`

Answer (score 0):

If you first correct the missing line of code:

```
 data1 = data11[complete.cases(data11),]
```

You can then merge and run table. (I don't have a "count" function in my R workspace.)

```
dmerge=merge( data1,data2, by=c("Id", "Id") )
 table( dmerge$Id, dmerge$Type )
 #-----------------------  
      Call Email NA Update Visit
  10121    0     1  0      0     0
  10122    0     1  0      0     0
  10123    0     1  0      0     0
  10124    0     1  0      0     0
  10125    0     1  0      0     0
  10126    0     1  0      0     0
  10127    0     2  2      0     0
  10129    0     0  0      1     0
  10130    0     0  0      1     0
    trimming the rest of a long table.....
```

Comment: Thank you I totally forgot abt the table cmd.

Answer (score 0):

**This is an R Markdown document.**

````
library(xlsx)

data11 <- read.xlsx("SampleData.xlsx", sheetName = "SampleData1", header = TRUE)
data22 <- read.xlsx("SampleData.xlsx", sheetName = "SampleData2", header = TRUE)


    data2 = data22[complete.cases(data22),]
    data1 = data11[complete.cases(data11),]
    data1$User = NA

    data2$User <- as.character(data2$User)

    for(i in data1[,1])
{
  for(q in data2[,1])
  {
      if(data1$Id[i] == data2$Id[q])
      {
  data1$User[i] = data2$User[q]
      }
  }
}

data.1 = data1[complete.cases(data1),]
summary(data1)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
 x1 <- subset(data.1, Type == "Email" )
 x2 <- subset(data.1, Type == "Update" )
x3 <- subset(data.1, Type == "NA" )
x4 <- subset(data.1, Type == "Call" )
x5 <- subset(data.1, Type == "Visit" )
```

```{r}
 newd <- table(data1$Type, data1$User)
 net = as.data.frame.matrix(newd)
 net$Total = net$A1001 + net$A1002 + net$A1003 + net$A1004 + net$A1005

 print(net)

```
````